# How to include angular JS expressions inside an SVG circle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have the following html code to create concentric circles.

```
<div id="delightmeter">

  {{delightScore}}
    <svg width='500px' height='300px' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>


            <g class=''>


                <circle class='' cx='200' cy='60' r='20'></circle>
                <circle class="" cx='200' cy='60' r='17' ></circle>


        </g>

    </svg>

</div>
```

I have another JS file in which i do some operations using angular JS and  i have the value in a $scope variable. Is there any way to access the variable from the other file and show it inside the svg circle

Update:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('delightMeterApp', [

])
    .directive('delightMeter', function () {
        function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {


            document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -90, -56));
            document.getElementById("arc2").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -54, -20));
            document.getElementById("arc3").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -18, 16));
            document.getElementById("arc4").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 18, 52));
            document.getElementById("arc5").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 54, 90));



            function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
                var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

                return {
                    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
                };
            }
            /* Function to draw single arcs recieving (start co-ordinateX,start co-ordinateY,radius,start angle, end angle) */
            function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

                var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
                var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);
                var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
                var d = [
                    "M", start.x, start.y,
                    "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
                ].join(" ");
                return d;
            }


            function ScoreRotateNeedle(delightScore) {
                $('.needleset').css({
                    "transform": "rotate(" + delightScore + "deg)",
                    "transform-origin": "50% 95%"
                });
            }

            $scope.$watch('score', function () {
                ScoreRotateNeedle($scope.score);
            });

        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'svgmeter.html',
            scope: {
                score: '=ngModel'
            },
            link: link
        };
    })
    .controller('delightMeterController', function ($scope) {
$scope.delightScore = 0;



    })
```

I need to access the `delightScore` variable from inside custom directive in my html template.

Comment: Need to be more specific than just `in another file`. We have no idea what scopes you are dealing with without more details. It sounds like you need a service to share data across controllers

Comment: Sooraj, Are you looking to display the value as "Text" inside your svg circle? Or trying to modify the circle attribute like radius or position using the value? Is this the same directive you are working on in your other question? More code on what your trying to do will help solve the issue -Shivas

Comment: @charlietfl i'm creating a custom directive and i need to use a variable from the link function in my template file. I have updated the question.

Comment: @ShivasJayaram I just want to bind the variable inside the JavaScript and just show it in the page. Yes it is part of the same question. I have updated the question.

Comment: where's the element `delight-meter` that directive is expecting? Please create a demo in plnkr.co

Comment: Here is the plunker demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/tWeNjM0H7F6npc2mM9L2?p=preview . I need the $scope.delightScore in svg.html template @charlietfl

Comment: i tried using `<foriegnObject>` tag. But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the plunker so that the delight score shows up as text in the SVG.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tWeNjM0H7F6npc2mM9L2?p=preview

Since you already have the value of delightScore in your directives scope called "score" you can use that in your SVG template as {{score}}

```
    <svg width='500px' height='300px' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>

    <g>
        <text x='100' y='220' fill='black'>0</text>
        **<text x='195' y='220' fill='black'>{{score}}</text>**
        <text x='300' y='220' fill='black'>100</text>
        <path class='arc' id='arc1' d='' />
        <path class='arc' id='arc2' d='' />
        <path class='arc' id='arc3' d='' />
        <path class='arc' id='arc4' d='' />
        <path class='arc' id='arc5' d='' />
        <g class='needleset'>
            <circle class='needle-center' cx='200' cy='200' r='5'></circle>
            <path class='needle' d='M 195 198 L 200 100 L 205 202'></path>
            <circle class='needle-center' cx='200' cy='200' r='5'></circle>
        </g>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Yes , that works. Thanks again. :)
I had tried the same , but it did not work due to a css issue. Only noticd it now. Thanks a  lot :)